# Finding the radius of convergence of a power series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to detemernine the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, where $(a_n)_{n=0,1,2,...}$ is given by $a_n=2-\dfrac{1}{2}a_{n-1}$ with $a_0=2/3$.

So far I've shown by induction that $2/3 \leq a_n \leq 5/3$, and specifically $7/6 \leq a_n \leq 5/3$ when $n\geq 2$ - I now have to use this information to determine the radius of convergence, but quite frankly I'm stumped.

My gut tells me, that the radius of convergence is $r=1$, so that $|x|<1$ makes the series convergent, but I have no formal argument.

Can anyone help me out?

Much appreciated.

Comment: The limit of $a_n$ is found from $a=2-a/2\implies a=4/3$, and we know that convergence is exponential. So we essentially have $\sum x^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=+\infty \tag{since $a_n\geq2/3$}$$
So the radius is $\leq1$.
On the other hand, if $0<x<1$, then:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5}{3}x^n<\infty$$
So the series converges for $|x|<1$

Therefore, the radius is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$2a_n-a_{n-1}=4$. From here: $2a_nx^n-a_{n-1}x^n=4x^n$. By summation:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2a_nx^n-a_{n-1}x^n)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4x^n\\
&=\frac{4x}{1-x}\,\,\,\, for\,\, |x|\lt 1
\end{align}
$$ For the left side of above equation, we can write: 
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2a_nx^n-a_{n-1}x^n)&=2(-a_0+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n)-x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\\
&=-\frac43 +(2-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
\end{align}
$$
So: $$(2-x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\frac{4x}{1-x}+\frac43$$   Then, the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is $1$.